# Google Sheets - The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-api

My Google Sheet apps script is trying to access YouTube API data.

In my console at cloud.google, I have defined projects, one of which has a YouTube API key.

I'm trying to use that key in a Google Sheets script.

It worked for a few days, up until yesterday, but I am now getting the error message

```
The API Key and the authentication credential are from different projects.
```

What does one have to do to link a Google sheet to the project defined in Google Console, so that I can successfully use that API Key?

My code:

```
let APIKey = "AIX...bQ0";
let chanID = "UC...Dw"

function getDetails() {
  channelId = chanID
  let info = YouTube.Channels.list("snippet, statistics", {id: channelId, key: APIKey} )
  Logger.log(info);
}
```

Comment: Apps Script sends your OAuth token from one project probably, and a key provided is from different project. What you can do is to switch Apps Script to second project mentioned, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project

Comment: Thanks for looking at this Kos.  I looked at that documentation, but it gets worse :)  I decided to change accounts, to a fully paid Google Workspace Business Starter account (from my old legacy account).  But it doesn't seem to accept any changes to the project, ïf I try to change it to a created project, of which I am the owner, it says "Project does not exist or you need edit access to it.  Damn, its quite a kerfuffle.

Comment: In this case I would recommend to create project from scratch.